# Eclipse: two windows, moving code editor from one window to the other

Tags: java, eclipse

I currently have two "main" windows in Eclipse (opened via Window -> New Window). I'd like to move one of the Java code editor windows from one of the "main" windows to the other one. Intuitively, one would drag & drop from one "main" window to the other, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm running Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800 on KDE 3.5

Comment: Are you running 2 instances of eclipse? Because when I open up a second main window I am able to move my editors without problems.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm running Eclipse on KDE 3.5 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work with version 4.2 (Juno) and up. Editor parts are bound to their parent window. They can be detached from it but not moved to a different one. You need to open the editor in the other window separately.

As Konstantin Komissarchik notes in the comments: "It is a regression as part of transitioning to the 4.x platform architecture. There is already a bug report. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon. http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384308"

Comment: I was able to move my editor from 1 window to the other without problems when I opened a second window via Window -> New Window. So I don't know why you're saying that it's impossible.

Comment: @JREN are you using Windows, by any chance?

Comment: @user1613 No I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: With what Eclipse release was this?

Comment: @his Eclipse SDK

Version: 4.2.1
Build id: M20120914-1800

Comment: @his Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: I could have sworn it wasn't possible with the old versions either. But checked with Indigo/Windows and it does.

Comment: Shall I post a bug report?

Comment: @user1613 It would be a feature request.

Comment: It is a regression as part of transitioning to the 4.x platform architecture. There is already a bug report. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384308

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik Thanks. I am pretty sure I head _some_ problems with this functionality in earlier versions - but I can't remember exactly anymore. Maybe OS dependent problems that I projected on the whole functionality. That said when I open different windows it is because of different functionality (e.g. J ava + SVN), not duplicate (e.g. Java + Java) so it doesn't annoys me personally.